# How to work on Play application locally

Tags: ssl, heroku, playframework

Hi I'm new to the play framework and Heroku. I was asked to worked on a play application hosted on Heroku that is written by someone else. The application has a PostgreSQL database attached to it.

I would like to know what's the best way to work on it. I don't want to have to push my app to heroku every time I make some changes to see the result.

the "play run" command is not working locally because of the remote database issue. I copy down the DATABASE_URL value and place it in the config file, but it still not work because it said "SSL off" and it seems to turn SSL on is not an easy thing.

Any thoughts on how I should work on this project?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a Heroku Postgres database from your local machine, an SSL connection must be used. To do so, you'll need to add the following query parameter to your database connection string:

```
?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Also, when running locally, I'd recommend using [Foreman](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally-with-foreman), which can read your Procfile and with inject environment variables, just like on Heroku. To set the environment variables to use, create (but don't check in) a `.env` file with the key-value pair you want available to your application. For example, something like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pass@ec2-107-22-182-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/db?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Then, you'll be able to run your app like this:

```
foreman run play run
```

Hint: To make creating the `.env` easier, checkout the [`heroku-config`](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config) plug-in, which provides a `heroku config:pull` command to pull the config from your app to a `.env` file. Of course, you'd probably want to be using a dev database for local development, but this would let you hit production if you so choose.